# Black (Python) Ignore Rule

Tags: python, python-black

I feel Black is doing something not compliant (with my Organisation), so I am trying to ignore certain rules.

Example below and a [related link](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/544)

`PEP 8: whitespace before ':'`

My Organisation (Coding Standards) does not give priority to what Black feels is right, but wants a way to customise black configurations.

I dont see any mentioned of Ignoring a Rule in Black documentation https://github.com/psf/black#command-line-options.

They have given examples to ignore Flake8 rules, but dont seem to have any documentation for their own product.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't customize black. From the [readme](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/master/README.md):

> Black reformats entire files in place. It is not configurable.

Comment: **The Uncompromising Code Formatter**. Indeed.

Answer (score 20):

While you can't cherry-pick certain rules to disable, you *can* skip formatting for individual lines (using `# fmt: skip` at the end of the line), or for blocks of code (start with `# fmt: off` and end with `# fmt: on`)

https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#code-style

And if using PyCharm, here's a guide for skipping certain lines without using the `fmt` comments: https://godatadriven.com/blog/partial-python-code-formatting-with-black-pycharm/

Edit: implement @kgadek correction

Comment: Small correction: you need to wrap a block of code with `# fmt: off` …code-block-here… `# fmt: on`